# jQuery focus on first input where ID is not

Tags: jquery, focus

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("input:text:visible:first").focus();
```

Which works fine and sets the focus on the first input field as required. The issue I am having is that on a certain page I do not want the first input (with `id="dSectors"`) to have focus. After a lot of searching I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
$("input:text:visible:first:not(#dSectors)").focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, just get rid of the `:first` and use `.first` afterward:

```
$("input:text:visible:not(#dSectors)").first().focus();
```

Example:

```js
$("input:text:visible:not(#dSectors)").first().focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dSectors">
<input type="text">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, you *can* do it in the selector, but `:first` has to be *after* `:not(#dSectors)`:

```
$("input:text:visible:not(#dSectors):first").focus();
```

Example:

```js
$("input:text:visible:not(#dSectors):first").focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dSectors">
<input type="text">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That only works because `:first` is a jQuery extension. In general, CSS selectors are additive, but some jQuery extensions don't work quite the way CSS does.